# Reference for first introduction to knot theory

Tags: reference-request

I've done a bit of reading using Colin Adams' The Knot Book, and have also read a good amount of Justin Roberts' [Knot Knotes](http://math.ucsd.edu/~justin/Papers/knotes.pdf), what resources have you found to be the most useful for learning knot theory for the first time?

Comment: Look here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8326/a-good-quick-introduction-to-knot-theory